# Conditional Probability question - is this info enough to solve it?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is exercise 3.97 from "Statistics for Business and Economincs", Ed. Newbold, 8th edition (I hope I am allowed to copy it here now that I've given attribution). I am struggling with solving it because I don't think there is enough information.

> A company places a rush order for wire of two thicknesses.
>   Consignments of each thickness are to be sent
>   immediately when they are available. Previous experience
>   suggests that the probability is 0.8 that at least
>   one of these consignments will arrive within a week. It
>   is also estimated that, if the thinner wire arrives within
>   a week, the probability is 0.4 that the thicker wire will
>   also arrive within a week. Further, it is estimated that,
>   if the thicker wire arrives within a week, the probability
>   is 0.6 that the thinner wire will also arrive within a
>   week.
>   a. What is the probability that the thicker wire will
>   arrive within a week?
>   b. What is the probability that the thinner wire will
>   arrive within a week?
>   c. What is the probability that both consignments
>   will arrive within a week?
>   Blockquote

Here is where I am with it:
Let T1= thin wire arrives within a week; T2= thick wire arrives within a week;
P(T1UT2) = 0.8; P(T2|T1) = 0.4; P(T1|T2) = 0.6
We are looking for: a) P(T1); b) P(T2); c) P(T1∩T2).

It seems to me, however, that this is not enough; that I would need either the intersection, or one of the individual probabilities. What am I missing? Or misunderstanding?

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram.  You are given three facts about the probabilities of the four regions in it and you know a fourth fact automatically (they sum to unity). Solve these equations.

Comment: @whuber, I can't draw the Venn diagram because two of the values given are conditional probabilities, which adds a time-factor, or a 3rd dimension, which I can't draw in 2-d. I could if this was an P(AUB) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B) type of question - but it isn't. Which is why I am struggling. :-(

Comment: There's no third dimension.  When you are told $\Pr(A \mid B) = 0.4,$ for instance, that's equivalent (according to the definition of conditional probability) to $0.4 = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)},$ implying $0.4 \Pr(B) = \Pr(A\cap B).$  That's a *linear* equation between two of the regions in the Venn diagram. You will have no problems solving this system of linear equations.

Comment: So that gives me 0.6T2=0.4T1, didn't get me far (I know the proportions but they can still be anything); also 0.6= 0.6T2/T2, in other words 0.6=0.6, not helpful either. If I take the union, I get T1= 0.8+1.6T2, which then gives T1|T1=0.6T2/0.8+1.6T2, which is obviously nonsense, given 0.4=/=0.25 ... (Also, this is a very basic chapter in an introductory book; I have the solution manual for all the even-numbered exercises in the chapter and none of those require anything like this, they are all just basic applications of the rules, so there has to be a simple solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following ratio:
$${{P(T_1|T_2)}\over{P(T_2|T_1)}}={P(T_1)\over P(T_2)}={3\over2}$$
You can write (let $P(T_1)=x$) $P(T_2),P(T_1\cap T_2)$ in terms of $x$.

Also, you have
$$P(T_1\cup T_2)=P(T_1)+P(T_2)-P(T_1\cap T_2)$$
in which you only have $x$ as the unknown.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it. I know I have P(T1∪T2)=P(T1)+P(T2)−P(T1∩T2), but of these I only know P(T1∪T2) and nothing to the right side of =, so I can't use formulas like P(T1|T2)= P(T1∩T2)/T2, because for these I'd need at least one of the individual probabilities (or the intersection). I am not quite sure of the first part of what you've written: I can't quite see why the two individual probabilities would have the same ratio as the conditional ones...

Comment: Write as $$P(T_1|T_2)=\frac{P(T_1\cap T_2)}{P(T_2)}$$

Comment: @Reader123 did you understand the answer?

Comment: No. (Also I'm sorry I can't write 'nice' equations - after your comment I checked the formatting help and it took me to a website of MathsJax or LaTex or whatever documentation - sorry, no capacity to learn all that at the moment.)

Comment: @Reader123 Let me write it more explicitly: $$\frac{P(T_1|T_2)}{P(T_2|T_1)}=\frac{\frac{P(T_1\cap T_2)}{P(T_2)}}{\frac{P(T_1\cap T_2)}{P(T_1)}}=\frac{P(T_1)}{P(T_2)}$$

Comment: Thanks, gunes, I understand this part now.I still can't solve the question though. This has only given me X=T1= two-thirdsT3, or 0.6T2=0.4T1. It doesn't tell me anything about what they are.  If I take the union, I get T1= 0.8+1.6T2, which then gives T1|T1=0.6T2/0.8+1.6T2, which is obviously nonsense, given 0.4=/=0.25 ...

Comment: @Reader123 let $P(T_1)=x$, then $P(T_2)=2x/3$, and $$0.4=P(T_2|T_1)=\frac{P(T_1\cap T_2)}{P(T_1)}\rightarrow P(T_1\cap T_2)=2x/5$$ Put these into equation of $P(T_1\cup T_2)$, and solve for $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much, gunes, for the time and effort you've put into explaining this to me; your patience is much appreciated.

Comment: To anyone interested in the solution, it follows from gunes's explanation that T1=0.63, T2=0.42 and T1∩T2=0.252

Comment: I have upvoted it - is there a separate button to accept a solution? Can't see anything like that... :|

Comment: Just under the lower arrow, there is a tick sign.